# Switch in loop to print out values

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, assign

I am working on Switch statement in a loop. I want to add names and assign letters to those names and then print out total value according to letters. The problem is it wont read assigned values for letters as you can see in my code below. For example, for Mike, I assigned A, and A has the value of 10. And for Joe, I assigned B, and B has the value of 7. So i need total value for A+B multiplied by fixed value of 3 which is 51. I am definitely doing something wrong and would like to know is it possible to do this without using objects and other methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TotalScore {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double lettervalue = 0,fixedvalue=3,totalvalue;
    int count,repeatcount;
    String valuename = "";
    String letter="";


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many values do you want to process? ");
count=input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();

for(repeatcount=0;repeatcount<count;++repeatcount){

System.out.print("Enter name for value " +(repeatcount+1)+" ");
valuename = valuename+input.nextLine()+"\n";
System.out.print("Enter letter A,B,C or D for named value ");
letter = letter+input.nextLine()+"\n";


switch(letter){
    case "A":case"a": lettervalue=10.0;
        break;
    case "B":case"b": lettervalue=7.0;
        break;

    case "C":case"c": lettervalue=5.0;
        break;
    case "D":case"d": lettervalue=2.0;
        break;
    default: lettervalue=0;



}

}
totalvalue=lettervalue*fixedvalue;
System.out.println("The value names are\n "+valuename);
System.out.println("The letter values you entered are\n "+letter);
System.out.println("The total value is "+totalvalue);



}

}

Output:
How many values do you want to process? 2
Enter name for value 1 Mike
Enter letter A,B,C or D for named value A
Enter name for value 2 Joe
Enter letter A,B,C or D for named value B
The value names are
   Mike
   Joe

The letter values you entered are
   A
   B

The total value is 0.0
```

Comment: `letter = letter+input.nextLine()+"\n"` will cause you to hit your default case every time in your switch statement.  Why are you appending a newline char? And then on the second iteration, `letter` will be the concatination of your two inputs and so on.

Comment: just to separate from the question to put those values underneath each other.

Comment: `letter` should only contain your input value, and then you can append that to a String if you need to

Comment: The thing i want to do is to  have something like this    Mike     A   10     and underneath   Joe      B     7

Comment: and then to calculate A and B and multiply with 3

Answer (score 1):

`letter` should only contain your input value. Then you can have a separate String to keep track of your total input.

```
String inputs = "";
String letter = "";

/*for loop etc.*/
letter = input.nextLine();

/*switch statement*/

inputs += valuename + letter + lettervalue + "\n";  //String.valueOf() is not necessary
totalvalue += lettervalue * fixedvalue;

/*end loop*/

System.out.println(inputs);
```

Comment: This is working as well. With String.valueOf() we are concatenating letters and getting value of lettervalue? never used String.valueof before thats why i am asking.

Comment: `String.valueOf()` basically takes a `Numeric` and converts it to a `String`.  Actually I don't think it's necessary. Made an edit.

Comment: Ok. I will play more with String.valueOf().  You meant it is not necessary to use String.valuOf in this example?

Comment: I actually don't think it's necessary to use it. You can concat with the int.

Comment: Got it. i will look at String.valueOf()  more for some other examples. It is useful when you can convert numeric to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be something like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TotalScore {

public static void main(String[] args) {
double lettervalue = 0,fixedvalue=3,totalvalue = 0.0;
int count,repeatcount;
String valuename = "";
String letter="";
String letters="";


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many values do you want to process? ");
count=input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();

for(repeatcount=0;repeatcount<count;++repeatcount){

System.out.print("Enter name for value " +(repeatcount+1)+" ");
valuename = valuename+input.nextLine()+"\n";
System.out.print("Enter letter A,B,C or D for named value ");
letter = input.nextLine();
letters = letters+letter;

switch(letter){
case "A":case"a": lettervalue=10.0;
    break;
case "B":case"b": lettervalue=7.0;
    break;

case "C":case"c": lettervalue=5.0;
    break;
case "D":case"d": lettervalue=2.0;
    break;
default: lettervalue=0;



}
totalvalue=totalvalue + lettervalue*fixedvalue;
}

System.out.println("The value names are\n "+valuename);
System.out.println("The letter values you entered are\n "+letters);
System.out.println("The total value is "+totalvalue);

}

}
```

This should be what you are looking for.

Had to make the following changes

1

```
totalvalue=totalvalue + lettervalue*fixedvalue;
```

2

```
moved the totalValue within the for loop
```

3

```
created a new variable letters to be the set of all the letters read.
```

Comment: Ok i see now. I had to compute letters using new string letters which i did not do and plus i did not compute totalvalue since it was not in the loop and i set it wrong. This way actually is working good. Good help, thanks a lot!